# переносимость кода

Tags: c++

Для тот, чтоб задать свой вопрос, написал тривиальную структуру

```
struct Test {
    const static size_t sz = sizeof(system(""));
    char s[sz]; // первое системное слово
    char ss;    // второе системное слово
    Test() :  ss('?')
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sz - 1; ++i)
            s[i] = 'a' + 1;
        s[sz] = sz + '0'; //инициализирую второе системное слово
    }
};
```

В принципе в структуре я инициализирую  символ с помощью выхода за пределы массива.

Теперь вопрос: Является ли это `UB` конкретно для данного определения?  И если у меня символ `ss` принимает то значение, что я присвоил `s[sz]`, то на других системах может быть другой принцип выравниваний полей?

Comment: Вообще-то непереносимо. Вы не можете полагаться на то или иное размещение переменных в памяти. Может использоваться выравнивание или что еще - короче говоря, полагаться на то, что в памяти поля будут располагаться именно так, а не иначе - нельзя.

Comment: @Harry, Все предельно ясно.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, вы всерьез предполагаете, что прототип `int system(const char *)` может измениться или таким образом определяете размер типа `int`?

Comment: @avp,  если вы имеете ввиду sizeof(system("")), то  это должен быть размер типа int на данной машине. Это просто импровизация

Comment: @avp,  это то же самое, что  вместо int* написать iterator_traits<int*>::pointer .   Иногда такая запись  по кайфу просто

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, ну, раз шутка, тогда я думаю, что на любой вменяемой (а на другие надо переносить свой код? -)) системе гэпа между `s` и `ss` не будет

Comment: @avp, нет, это переносить никуда не нужно. Просто  хотелось выяснить, заодно вам не будет скучно, а то вопросов мало...